# Algebraic variety as a union of nonsingular subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

#### Definitions

Let $M$ be algebraic variety and let $I$ be the defining ideal of $M$, that is
$$I(M) = \{ f \in K[X_1,...,X_n] \mid \forall x \in M : f(x)=0 \}$$
Let $f_1,...,f_m$ be the generators of $I(M)$. Let
$$ J = \frac{\partial(f_1,...,f_m)}{\partial(X_1,...,X_n)}$$
be the Jacobian matrix.

A point $x \in M$ in an algebraic variety is called simple if $\mathrm{rk}J(x)=\mathrm{rk}(J)$ where rk is the rank of the $J$. The notation $J(x)$ is the matrix $J$ evaluated in $x \in M$. Clearly, $\mathrm{rk}J(x) \le \mathrm{rk}(J)$.

Let us denoted by $M^{\mathrm{reg}}$ the set of all simple points of $M$. A non-simple point is called regular. A nonsingular variety is a variety without non-simple points.

#### I want to prove the following:

Any algebraic variety $M$ is the union of finite number of nonintersecting nonsingular
subvarieties. That is, $$M = \biguplus_{i=1}^q M_i$$

#### My attempt

If $M$ is nonsingular then we won. Therefore assume there are singular (non-simple) points in $M$.

Let $M = N_1 \cup ... \cup N_q$ be the decomposition of $M$ into irreducible components. Take one
of the $M_i$ to be $M^{\mathrm{reg}}$ which is nonsingular. Now I need to add the rest of the singular points such they each is included in a subvariety in which it is simple. Therefore, I somehow need to take the singular points such that each is contained in a single irreducible component and is simple there (but not in $M$).

Comment: Can you do it for the variety $xy=0$ in the plane?

Comment: In that case you take the open subvariety $M^{\mathrm{reg}}$ defined by the algebra $K[x,y]_{I(0,0)}$ (by that I mean the localization of $K[x,y]$ by the ideal of functions that vanish at $(0,0)$) and then $M = M^{\mathrm{reg}} \uplus \{ (0,0) \}$.

Comment: Do you know that simple points form an nonempty open set?

Comment: @Sanchez Yes. So if we take $N_i^{\mathrm{reg}} \subset N_i$ then it is dense ($N_i$ is irreducible). But does it imply that $N_i - N_i^{\mathrm{reg}}$ contains finitely many points? If it is true then I take the singleton subvarieties of these points.

Comment: I think, at least in char. $0,$ one can stratify $M$ into locally closed nonsingular subvarieties by e.g. embedding $M$ into a regular $W$ and using the order of vanishing of points along the ideal (sheaf) of $M$. This is an important step in resolution of singularities. It is not true that the singular locus must be finitely many points.

Comment: If I understand your hint, let us denote $\mu = \mathrm{rk}(J)$ and $$ M_s= \{ x \in M \mid \mathrm{rk}J(x) = s \} \ .$$ Then $M_\mu = M^{\mathrm{reg}}$ and $$ M = \biguplus_{s=0}^{\mu} M_s \ . $$ It remains to show that $M^{(s)}$ are indeed subvarieties.

Comment: @LinAlgMan, $N_i - N_i^{reg}$ may not be finite, but it is closed and of lower dimension.

Comment: Dear @LinAlgMan, I think that might work. Maybe it is worth checking against an example, e.g. $V(xyz)\subseteq\mathbb A^3.$

Comment: @Andrew In that case $$J = [ yz , xz , xy ]^t$$ and $\mathrm{rk}J=1$. For the axes (e.g. $x=y=0$) we have $\mathrm{rk}J|_{\mathrm{axes}} = 0$ and for the planes (e.g. $x=0$) we have the $\mathrm{rk}J|_{\mathrm{planes}}=1$. The origin has also rank 0 and it is included in each axis and plane. So we may removed it from them and thus get open subvarieties. It is remained to check that the union of axes is a subvariety and the union of the planes is subvarieties. However, their entire union of all the planes and axes is not disjoint, so we need somehow to fix this.

Comment: A small correction: the planes are punctured ones, without the axes, since in each axis the rank is 0 and not 1. So the rank=1 planes and the rank=0 axes are disjoint. We take the punctured axes (without the origin) and add it as a separate subvariety. It probably related to the fact that the origin $x=y=z=0$ has zero of order 2 in every element of $J$.

Comment: @LinAlgMan, sorry, I realized almost immediately after posting (and walking away from my computer!) that this is a good example to see that vanishing order is *different* from rank of $J.$ Indeed, $\mathrm{rk}(J)$ is $0,1$ as you say, but the orders of points in $\mathbb A^3$ can be $0,1,2,3$ depending on how many hyperplanes pass through them. So, "order" here means lowest order of nonzero terms in the Taylor series of a defining equation (e.g. $f=xyz$) at a chosen point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To amplify Sanchez's comment: suppose the ground field is perfect (e.g. algebraically closed or of characteristic $0$). Then $M_0:=M^{reg}$ is open and dense in $M$. So $N_1:=M\setminus M_0$ is a closed subset of $M$ of dimension $\dim N_1 <  \dim M$. Endow $N_1$ with the structure of reduced closed subvariety of $M$. Let 
$$M_1=N_1^{reg}, \quad N_2=N_1\setminus M_1, \quad M_2=N_2^{reg} \dots $$
This sequence stops because $\dim N_{n+1} < \dim N_n$. So 
$$ M = M_0 \cup M_1 \cup ... $$ 
(finite disjoint union of smooth subvarieties). If you want integral smooth subvarieties, you can replace each $M_i$ by the disjoint union of its connected components.

Comment: Is there anything we can say about nonsingular points over imperfect fields? (As in dense/open?) I don't know where perfectness came in..

Comment: Dear @Sanchez: the set of nonsingular points is always open, but can be empty. The simplest example is the spec of a finite radicial extension of the ground field. However, the set of regular points is open and dense (if the variety is reduced). Regularity coincides with smoothness (=nonsingularity) over perfect fields.

Comment: Dear @user18119: your terminology is not the standard one. Regular and non-singular are synonyms and are absolute notions, not depending on a base scheme. Smoothness depends on some base scheme and means: regular and remaining regular after any base-change.See [section 27.9](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02IR)  in the Stacks Project. See also section 12.2.3 in Vakil's [Foundations of algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf).